# How to create a graphics window with size based on number of data items within an imported file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a graphics window that has a size which is dependent upon how many lines are within a text document that I am importing, and I'll be multiplying that by some arbitrary number (like 50) so that I can give space for pixels and other content. The problem is: I don't know how many lines are within this text document. It could contain 10 lines, or 30. The text file is called `input.txt`

Here is my code:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    infile = open("input.txt", "r")
    data = infile.read()

    lines = infile.readlines()
    x = lines * 50
    y = lines * 50


    win = GraphWin("Student Exam Scores", x, y)



main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the number of lines with `len(lines)`. However, you'll need to reset the read position before you call `infile.readlines()`, because the previous call to `infile.read()` moved it to the end. To do that, call `infile.seek(0)`.

So your sample code would need to change to (only typing out the relevant bit):

```
    data = infile.read()
    infile.seek(0)

    lines = infile.readlines()
    numLines = len(lines)

    x = numLines * 50
    y = numLines * 50
```

Comment: Damn, I knew it would have something to do with len, although using len(lines) is a fantastic idea. Thanks for the tips, really helps me with my homework. Also, thank you for explaining the .seek function.